# Getting Linking errors using BLuetoothAPIs.h in vs 2017 and windows 10

Tags: c++, bluetooth, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, lnk2019

Using the following code:

// Bluetooth_test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "bthdef.h"
#include "BluetoothAPIs.h"

int main()
{
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS bptsp;

    // set options for how we want to load our list of BT devices
    bptsp.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS);
    bptsp.fReturnAuthenticated = TRUE;
    bptsp.fReturnRemembered = TRUE;
    bptsp.fReturnUnknown = TRUE;
    bptsp.fReturnConnected = TRUE;
    bptsp.fIssueInquiry = TRUE;
    bptsp.cTimeoutMultiplier = 4;
    bptsp.hRadio = NULL;

    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO bptdi;
    bptdi.dwSize = sizeof(bptdi);

    HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND hFind = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&bptsp, &bptdi);

    BluetoothFindDeviceClose(hFind);


    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _BluetoothFindFirstDevice@8 referenced in function _main Bluetooth_test  D:\VS 2017\repos\Bluetooth_test\Bluetooth_test\Bluetooth_test.obj   1   
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  Bluetooth_test  D:\VS 2017\repos\Bluetooth_test\Debug\Bluetooth_test.exe    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _BluetoothFindDeviceClose@4 referenced in function _main Bluetooth_test  D:\VS 2017\repos\Bluetooth_test\Bluetooth_test\Bluetooth_test.obj   1
```

I am pretty new to C++ and I have no clue why it won't compile please help me

Windows API's:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfindfirstdevice
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfinddeviceclose

==== EDIT ====
Like Mike Petrichenko said in the comments, the errors won't acure when I add `#pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib");` underneath the includes.

Comment: #pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib");

Comment: @MikePetrichenko THANK YOU SO MUCH, this is the answer

Comment: At the bottom of the documentation in the "Requirements" section, it lists what library you need.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you very much I just noticed how this works